# How to I export the IIS list of certificates into a detailed list?

Tags: iis, ssl

I wish to export the list of certificates installed on the my IIS into to a detailed list (Name, domain, expiration date and so forth) into a list.

I wish to upload it to my calendar so I'll know when to renew them.

Comment: It is not controlled by IIS, but part of Windows as the computer account's Personal certificate store. Thus, you need to learn some query methods such as PowerShell or WMI.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a powrshell script which does that.
I have used notepadd++ find & replace commands to make a proper CSV out of it.

```
# Get all certs in MY store of Local Machine profile
 $store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My","LocalMachine")
 $store.Open("ReadOnly")
 $store.Certificates | 
 % { 
 # Get all extensions for one cert
 $cert = $_
 $cert.Extensions | 
 % { 
 # Find "Enhanced Key Usage" extension
 $extension = $_
 If ($extension.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Enhanced Key Usage")
 {
 # Get all enhanced key usages for the cert
 $enhancedKeyUsageExtension = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]$extension
 $enhancedKeyUsageExtension.EnhancedKeyUsages | 
 % { 
 # Find "Server Authentication" enhanced key usage
 $enhancedKeyUsage = $_
 If ($enhancedKeyUsage.FriendlyName -eq "Server Authentication") 
 {
 # We found a cert that will get listed in Server Certificates list in IIS Manager. Show its info 
 $cert | Select Subject, Issuer, NotBefore, NotAfter, Thumbprint, SerialNumber
 } 
 }
 } 
 }
 }
 $store.Close()
```

You can run it in a ps1 file from the power shell command line and save the results into a file.
something like this:
.\getSSL.ps1 | Out-File myfile.txt